# Visual Studio moves labels when I run my program

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

My window design looks good and how I want it to look but, once I run my program, the labels move and resize along with the buttons. This is also happening with my other window is well. I'm running on Windows 10 and I'm also using Visual Studio 2017.

Here's how my design window is suppose to look

[image: How it should look]

Here's how it looks once I execute the program

[image: How it looks]

Here is my `InitializeComponent` function:

```
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
        this.welcomeLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.contactDeveloperLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.addProductsButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.viewProductsButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.addSuppliersButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.deleteProductsButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.editProductsButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.quickEditButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.contactDeveloper = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.shopStockLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // welcomeLabel
        // 
        this.welcomeLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(21, 51);
        this.welcomeLabel.Name = "welcomeLabel";
        this.welcomeLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(297, 120);
        this.welcomeLabel.TabIndex = 2;
        this.welcomeLabel.Text = resources.GetString("welcomeLabel.Text");
        this.welcomeLabel.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        // 
        // contactDeveloperLabel
        // 
        this.contactDeveloperLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(36, 241);
        this.contactDeveloperLabel.Name = "contactDeveloperLabel";
        this.contactDeveloperLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(268, 40);
        this.contactDeveloperLabel.TabIndex = 3;
        this.contactDeveloperLabel.Text = "If any problem occurs please contact\r\nthe developer immediately ";
        this.contactDeveloperLabel.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        // 
        // addProductsButton
        // 
        this.addProductsButton.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.addProductsButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(21, 178);
        this.addProductsButton.Name = "addProductsButton";
        this.addProductsButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(93, 28);
        this.addProductsButton.TabIndex = 4;
        this.addProductsButton.Text = "Add Products";
        this.addProductsButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.addProductsButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.addProductsButton_Click);
        // 
        // viewProductsButton
        // 
        this.viewProductsButton.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.viewProductsButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(224, 178);
        this.viewProductsButton.Name = "viewProductsButton";
        this.viewProductsButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(93, 28);
        this.viewProductsButton.TabIndex = 5;
        this.viewProductsButton.Text = "View Products";
        this.viewProductsButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // addSuppliersButton
        // 
        this.addSuppliersButton.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.addSuppliersButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(122, 178);
        this.addSuppliersButton.Name = "addSuppliersButton";
        this.addSuppliersButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(93, 28);
        this.addSuppliersButton.TabIndex = 6;
        this.addSuppliersButton.Text = "Add Suppliers";
        this.addSuppliersButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // deleteProductsButton
        // 
        this.deleteProductsButton.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.deleteProductsButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(21, 212);
        this.deleteProductsButton.Name = "deleteProductsButton";
        this.deleteProductsButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(93, 28);
        this.deleteProductsButton.TabIndex = 7;
        this.deleteProductsButton.Text = "Delete Products";
        this.deleteProductsButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // editProductsButton
        // 
        this.editProductsButton.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.editProductsButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(122, 212);
        this.editProductsButton.Name = "editProductsButton";
        this.editProductsButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(93, 28);
        this.editProductsButton.TabIndex = 8;
        this.editProductsButton.Text = "Edit Products";
        this.editProductsButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // quickEditButton
        // 
        this.quickEditButton.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.quickEditButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(224, 212);
        this.quickEditButton.Name = "quickEditButton";
        this.quickEditButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(93, 28);
        this.quickEditButton.TabIndex = 9;
        this.quickEditButton.Text = "Quick Edit";
        this.quickEditButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // contactDeveloper
        // 
        this.contactDeveloper.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.contactDeveloper.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(115, 283);
        this.contactDeveloper.Name = "contactDeveloper";
        this.contactDeveloper.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(110, 28);
        this.contactDeveloper.TabIndex = 10;
        this.contactDeveloper.Text = "Contact Developer";
        this.contactDeveloper.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // shopStockLabel
        // 
        this.shopStockLabel.AutoSize = true;
        this.shopStockLabel.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 26.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.shopStockLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(66, 10);
        this.shopStockLabel.Name = "shopStockLabel";
        this.shopStockLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(204, 39);
        this.shopStockLabel.TabIndex = 11;
        this.shopStockLabel.Text = "Shop Stock";
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(9F, 20F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.AutoSize = true;
        this.AutoValidate = System.Windows.Forms.AutoValidate.EnablePreventFocusChange;
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Silver;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(339, 323);
        this.Controls.Add(this.shopStockLabel);
        this.Controls.Add(this.contactDeveloper);
        this.Controls.Add(this.quickEditButton);
        this.Controls.Add(this.editProductsButton);
        this.Controls.Add(this.deleteProductsButton);
        this.Controls.Add(this.addSuppliersButton);
        this.Controls.Add(this.viewProductsButton);
        this.Controls.Add(this.addProductsButton);
        this.Controls.Add(this.contactDeveloperLabel);
        this.Controls.Add(this.welcomeLabel);
        this.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 5, 4, 5);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.SizeGripStyle = System.Windows.Forms.SizeGripStyle.Hide;
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }
```

Thank You.

Comment: That appears to be due to windows styles. You will just need to work with your design to ensure things are sized, aligned, spaced, anchored, etc... properly to ensure things will reasonably look correct depending upon the different styles that users may operate with. There is no real "magic bullet", you just need to play with your formatting. You could also perhaps use a `TableLayoutPanel` to help a little.

Comment: Also, perhaps add to your question, include the code you have in your `InitializeComponent` function in your form designer code document. That way we could take a look at how you are setting your controls up.

Comment: First check the font you are using. Second see the size of those components and be sure if the text can fit properly. Third see the anchor of those components and the last one you should definitely change the size of the form because there are always some irregularities with the design itself when making components that small. If you somehow want to use that size of the form you should use VS Blend to deal with the design.

Comment: I understand that, but it still generates the designer code whenever you create a form like this. That is how the layout is handled. It may look visual, but it is all still just code in the forms Designer code file (`Form1.Designer.cs`). Open that file and copy the `InitializeComponent` function and add it to your question. That has all of the form element settings in it.

Comment: Is there a reason you are pulling some of your text from a resource? If you are pulling variable data from somewhere, you can definitely end up with an unpredictable layout. If that is what you need, then you will need to work on dynamically formatting your layout to take that into account, but that seems rather unnecessary for what this appears to be. Also, I see no reason to list out what functions are available when they are already listed with the buttons. You could even get rid of all of those buttons and put your choices in a dropdown with a single button to activate the selected item.

Comment: Thank You gmiley, I am kind of new to stackoverflow but how do I say the question is answered

P.S - I fixed it with a suggestion above

Comment: it was the first one you did

Comment: could you add it below please

Comment: and foxes one as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That appears to be due to windows styles. You will just need to work with your design to ensure things are sized, aligned, spaced, anchored, etc... properly to ensure things will reasonably look correct depending upon the different styles that users may operate with. There is no real "magic bullet", you just need to play with your formatting. You could also perhaps use a TableLayoutPanel to help a little. It might also help some to make the overall size of the form a bit bigger and space your elements out more as well as make the buttons a bit bigger.

Also, as some further suggestions/thoughts:

Is there a reason you are pulling some of your text from a resource? If you are pulling variable data from somewhere, you can definitely end up with an unpredictable layout. If that is what you need, then you will need to work on dynamically formatting your layout to take that into account, but that seems rather unnecessary for what this appears to be.

Also, I see no reason to list out what functions are available within the text when they are already listed below that with the buttons. You could even get rid of all of those buttons and put your choices in a dropdown list with a single button to activate the selected item.